# Facebook graph api search in page conversations by user name

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I am using facebook graph api with this edge
`me/conversations?fields=participants`

[Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/270495630093399?method=GET&path=me%2Fconversations%3Ffields%3Dparticipants&version=v2.10)

this get list of conversation for my page using page access token. Now i need to search in this list by user name

Any suggestion to do that directly with API or any workaround ?

Comment: The API provides no way to do this.

Comment: Depending on your use case you can check the `senders` field. But as @CBroe already said, there is no way to this via API. You have to do it on your end.

Comment: My use case i need to send message to certain user ... so i need to search for him then send a message. So i need to reach his conversation directly

Comment: I'm having the same use case and I've seen [ManyChat](https://manychat.com) does the same ... Not sure how they can do it.

Comment: @sonlexqt ManyChat saving the new conversations to their database and then it is doable to search within their database ... that's why they can search in contacts

Comment: But in this case we need to get all conversations on the fly from Facebook API without saving any data on our side ... then we trying to do search on this list via API directly

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround you can call with the `limit` parameter set:
`me/conversations?fields=participants&limit=500`
It will show you 500 latest threads. Then cmd+f (ctrl+f) and type the name you are looking for.